# RunMetadata in eager mode

Tags: tensorflow

Does eager mode support `tf.profiler` in r1.8? Since it no longer has the session object, is there any way to pass in a `tf.RunMetadata()` into the execution? I saw the profiler constructor checks for eager mode; but without `RunMetadata` it doesn't work. Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
with context.eager_mode():
  outfile = os.path.join(test.get_temp_dir(), 'dump')
  opts = builder(
      builder.time_and_memory()).with_file_output(outfile).build()

  context.enable_run_metadata()

  # run your model here #

  profiler = model_analyzer.Profiler()
  profiler.add_step(0, context.export_run_metadata())
  context.disable_run_metadata()
  profiler.profile_operations(opts)
```

You may refer to the below link (testEager function). https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/profiler/model_analyzer_test.py

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow seongsik park. While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)